# Expression builder in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am searching for an expression builder GUI (like the one used in Microsoft Access). It can be plain Javascript or JQuery plugin. I am loathe to build my own and reinvent the wheel if one already exists - and yet, a search on Google does not find anything remotely useful.

Is anyone aware of any such library/plugin or article that covers this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SQL_QUERY_BUILDER?  Its not pretty, but it seems like it could get the job done.

Comment: yarmiganosca: Eeek! I took a look - its kinda messed up though. It may be easier to write one from scratch. I'll wait a while and see if there are any other suggestions.

Comment: @morpheous could you let me know if you tried to build one ? Would be helpful if you could link me to it. Thanks!